# JavaFX access parent Controller class from FXML child

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

using JavaFX for an application and I have a Main.fxml file with some fxml child files inside it.

I would like to access to MainController class of Main.fxml from the child Controllers.

I'll try to explain better with an example:

MainFxml:

```
    <HBox fx:controller="MainController.java">
        <fx:include source="child.fxml"/>
    </HBox>
```

MainController:

```
    public class MainController implements Initializable {
            private String string;
            public void setString (String string) {
                    this.string = string;
            }
```

ChildFxml:

```
    <HBox fx:id="child" fx:controller="ChildController.java">
        <Button text="hello" onAction="#selectButton"></Button>
    </HBox>
```

ChildController:

```
    public class ChildController implements Initializable {
            @FXML HBox child;
            @FXML Button button;
            @FXML
            public void selectButton (ActionEvent event) {
                // here call MainController.setString("hello");
            }
```

I tried [this solution found on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class) but I need to get the Controller reference of the Main.fxml that has been already loaded.
Is there any method to get the Controller starting from a specific Pane?
Something like:

```
    // child.getParent().getController();
```

Comment: Maybe you can share a `StringProperty` object between `ChildController` and `MainController` so MainController can update itself when the string changes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266498/when-to-use-stringproperty-over-string for some more info.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you assign a `fx:id` to the `<fx:include>` tag, `FXMLLoader` tries to inject the the controller of the included fxml to a field named `<fx:id>Controller`. You can pass the `MainController` reference to the child controllers in the `initialize` method:

```xml
<HBox fx:controller="MainController.java">
    <fx:include fx:id="child" source="child.fxml"/>
</HBox>
```

#### MainController

```
@FXML
private ChildController childController;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    childController.setParentController(this);
}
```

#### ChildController

```
private MainController parentController;

public void setParentController(MainController parentController) {
    this.parentController = parentController;
}

@FXML
private void selectButton (ActionEvent event) {
    this.parentController.setString("hello");
}
```

---

It would however be better practice to keep the `ChildController` independent from the parent. This could be done by providing a `StringProperty` in the `ChildController` that gets set to the value the parent should display.

#### ChildController

```
private final StringProperty value = new SimpleStringProperty();

public StringProperty valueProperty() {
    return value;
}

@FXML
private void selectButton (ActionEvent event) {
    value.set("hello");
}
```

#### ParentController

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    childController.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> setString(newValue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in my own projects with the use of the `Singleton` model. You can use a separate class to keep references to parent controllers.

For example:

**Global.java:**

```
public class Global {

    public static ParentControllerClass parentController;

    private Global() {
    }

    public static ParentControllerClass getParentController() {
        return mainApp;
    }

    public static void setParentController(ParentControllerClass parentController) {
        Global.parentController = parentController;
    }
}
```

Within your parent controller, you would just need to pass a reference to itself to the `Global` class by calling `Global.setParentController(this);`. You can then access it from the child by using the Getter: `Global.getParentController();`

This is preferable to having the parent and child share the same controller as it helps to keep your code cleaner and easier to read.

I am fairly new to Java myself and this may not be the most sophisticated method to use for this scenario, but it has worked perfectly for me thus far.

Comment: This approach will be a trouble when you have multiple stage in your application