# View Injection in FXML

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        

BorderPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("mainView.fxml"));
```

When i run this it doesnt show the injected views

Im building a new application with JavaFX for the main page im using 3 views build by 3 fxml files
each view has its controller. for the main page i want to inject the three fxml files in a mainView.fxml via fx:include the mainView.fxml has also a controller how can i do that?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<fx:root alignment="CENTER_LEFT" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="93.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-min-width: 800; -fx-min-height: 100; -fx-spacing: 30;" type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="title" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="91.0" prefWidth="179.0" style="-fx-label-padding: 20; -fx-line-spacing: 20;" text="News" textFill="#00a4f2">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="36.0" />
         </font>
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </opaqueInsets></Label>
      <Button fx:id="refresh" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-alignment: CENTER; -fx-background-color: #66a6ff;" text="Button" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
         </opaqueInsets></Button>
      <Button fx:id="stat" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #feada6;" text="Button">
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
         </opaqueInsets></Button>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

This is per example the topView.fxml

```
package ch.bfh.spacenews;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class TopBarController extends HBox {

    @FXML
    public Label title;
    @FXML
    public Button refresh;
    @FXML
    public Button stat;
    
    TopBarController(){
        FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("topView.fxml"));
        load.setRoot(this);
        load.setController(this);
        try {
            System.out.println("TopBarController");
            load.load();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the corresponding controller of the topView.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>


<BorderPane fx:controller="ch.bfh.spacenews.mainController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <fx:include fx:id="topBar" source="topView.fxml"/>
   </top>
   
   <center>
    <fx:include fx:id="article" source="sample.fxml"/>
   </center>
   
   <right>
      <fx:include fx:id="seacrh" source="searchView.fxml"/>  
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

This is where i want to inject the topView.fxml

```
package ch.bfh.spacenews;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;



public class mainController {
    
    @FXML
    TopBarController topBarController;
    @FXML
    ArticleController articleController;
    @FXML
    SearchController searchController;
    
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        
    }

}
```

And this is the Controller of the mainView.fxml where i want to inject the topView.fxml

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807580/javafx-access-parent-controller-class-from-fxml-child/44808155 answer this question for you?

Comment: Well im pretymuch triyng the same thing but i just simply want to show the three different views i created in the mainView.fxml but wen i load the mainView.fxml it doesnt happen

Comment: [mcve] please .. and stick to  java naming conventions

Comment: @WillHartung That example is actually different; the FXML custom component pattern (https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) relies on custom node subclasses; it doesn't use `<fx:include>`.

Answer (score 1):

In the [FXML custom component pattern](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) the controller classes also serve as the wrapper for the view, by subclassing an appropriate `Node` subclass. This means you can just instantiate them directly in the FXML via the `FXMLLoader`. For example, the `<TopBarController>` element instructs the `FXMLLoader` to instantiate the `TopBarController` by calling its no-argument constructor. That constructor, as per your code, loads `topView.fxml`, etc. There is no need to use `<fx:include>`, which is an instruction for the `FXMLLoader` to load another FXML file, since you already have code in your `TopBarController` to do that.

So your main view FXML file should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<?import ch.bfh.spacenews.TopBarController?>
<!-- other imports... -->


<BorderPane fx:controller="ch.bfh.spacenews.MainController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <TopBarController fx:id="topBar" />
   </top>
   
   <center>
    <ArticleController fx:id="article" />
   </center>
   
   <right>
      <SearchController fx:id="search" />  
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

And the corresponding controller is

```
package ch.bfh.spacenews;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;



public class MainController {
    
    @FXML
    TopBarController topBar;
    @FXML
    ArticleController article;
    @FXML
    SearchController search;
    
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        
    }

}
```

Note that it's really critical to follow standard naming conventions here. The `FXMLLoader` explicitly relies on the case of an element to determine if it's referring to a class name or a property name.

Comment: yeah, happens to us over and over again, that's what made me giggle :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Main class : Launch.java

```
public class Launch extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Controller.show(stage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can add view from controller :

```
public class Controller {
    public BorderPane mainPane; // fx:id of your pane
    public static Stage current;

    public static void show(Stage stage) {
        this.current = stage;
        Scene scene = null;
        BorderPane pane = null;
        try {
            scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainView.fxml")));
            pane = (BorderPane) scene.lookup("#mainPane");

            // Add .fxml view to mainView
            pane.setCenter(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml")));
            pane.setTop(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("topView.fxml")));
            pane.setRight(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("searchView.fxml")));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        stage.setTitle("MainView");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```